# How do I get Javascript to run animation instead of CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am doing a splash screen for my website. I have managed to get it working as JS wasn't working.

```
"use strict";

$(function(){
    $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
    setInterval(function(){
      $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
         .next('img').fadeIn()
         .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
     6000);
});


const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=> {
    setTimeout(function()=> {
        splash.classList.add('display-none');
    }, 10000);
})
```

The bottom code breaks the top code (which works and runs the slideshow).

```
.splash {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: 200;
}

.splash.display-none {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0; 
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: -10;
    transition: all 6s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    to{
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
    to{
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}

.splash {
    opacity: 1;
    animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in forwards;
    -webkit-animation: fadeIn 2s ease-in forwards;
    animation-delay: 0.75s;
}

.fade-in {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is my CSS, and the animation works. My only problem with it is that if I went back to homepage, the animation would happen again. This is why I want to use Javascript so it only happens on a new instance of loading the website.

Comment: Check this out : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_animate.asp, try this as your starting point and let me know if that is what you needed. It is the bare bones of using pure js for animation.

Comment: @JonNezbit The CSS animation already works. And HTML is favouring the CSS animation over the JS one. https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=391&v=MOlaldp1Fv4&feature=emb_logo <- this guide helped me.

Comment: remove the animation classes from your HTML, and add them with JS depending on your detection of a new instance

Comment: I would use JavaScript to add and remove an HTML class. Do use a CSS animation. Use `sessionStorage` so you know the page has already run the CSS animation.

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to see if splash screen has been shown already.  Set them to `display:none` immediately so they are completely hidden.  I'm not sure what you actually want to happen with the splash, so I'm just hiding them completely.  I think it would be more pleasant to just have a very short opacity transition instead.

You can use localStorage.removeItem to clear the splashed flag.

You may want to use a unique ID  for the localStorage name for this specific splash, and not just "splashed".

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (e)=> {
    const splashed = localStorage.getItem('splashed')
    const splash = document.querySelector('.splash');
    const splasher = () => {
        splash.classList.add('display-none');
        localStorage.setItem('splashed',1)
    };
    splashed ? splash.forEach(x=>x.style.display='none') : setTimeout(splasher, 10000);
})
```

Comment: Thanks, This is the splash I'm trying to imitate

https://www.lottiedavies.com/

The source code is a mess. I can't make head nor tail of it.